Why is the C++ standard definition of 'coherenced-order before' different from the paper it is based on?
This proposal introduced a change to the behavior of sequentially consistent memory model in C++20. The proposal is based on this paper.
The standard introduces a relation called 'coherenced-ordered before' defined as follows:

[atomics]
An atomic operation A on some atomic object M is coherence-ordered before another atomic operation B on M if

A is a modification, and B observes A, or
A precedes B in the modification order, or
A and B are not the same atomic read-modify-write operation, and there exists an atomic modification X of M such that A observes the value stored by X and X precedes B in the modification order of M, or
there exists X such that A is coherence-ordered before X and X is coherence-ordered before B.


This definition seems to be based on the 'extended coherence order' relation defined in the paper above with only one difference: the third point in the standard restricts A and B to only read-modify-write operation (bolded part). However, in the paper, it is possible for A to be an atomic read operation and B to be an atomic write operation as they are defined using a 'read-before' relation.
This seems weird to me since the proposal itself also states that:

The definition of "coherence-ordered before" is essentially standard terminology, but was not previously part of our standard. The third bullet corresponds to what's often called "reads before": A reads a write earlier than B.

Another paper, which introduces the RC20 memory model, also defines 'read-before' ('from-read') without the read-modify-write restriction.
So why is there a mismatch between the standard and the paper it is based on? Are there any reasons why the standard 'weakens' the 'coherence-ordered before' relation?
Considering the following example:
// Thread 1
x.load(std::memory_order::seq_cst); // 0

// Thread 2
x.store(1, std::memory_order::seq_cst);

Assuming that x is initialized with 0, does this mean it is possible for the load to come after the store in the strict total order S? since they do not form a 'strongly-happen-before' relation and neither of them are read-modify-write operations.

Papers are sketches, often are different from the standard.

@3CxEZiVlQ I just added an example at the bottom of the post. I don't think the example violates the coherence but it seems unintuitive to have the store comes before the load in S.

"the third point in the standard restricts A and B to only read-modify-write operation (bolded part)." -- I don't read the bolded part as restricting A and B to only read-modify-write operations. If A (or B) is not an atomic read-modify-write operation, then it trivially cannot be the same atomic read-modify-write operation as something else. So the clause would still apply. The restrictions I see are that A must include a read (in order to observe) and B must include a modify (to be in the modification order). Is there some other context that implies the restriction you see?

@JaMiT Your explanation makes sense to me. Being read-modify-write is not the precondition of the clause but it is there to prevent 'read-before' relation from forming a self-loop. Now, the definition is identical to 'read-before'. Thanks for the help!
